# How to use a worker dyno to read from a local path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I'm trying to process a CSV file from a user's local machine using a worker on heroku. Everything works on my dev environment but when I try to run it on heroku, it can't read the temp file from a web dyno to a worker dyno.

Is there a way to tell a worker the local path, the worker reads the CSV file from that path and does the processing in the background?

Do I need to use paperclip to upload the file to S3 first and then do the processing? I don't need to store the file at all, just need to read it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different dynos have completely separate [filesystems](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): you'll have to copy the file somewhere persistent, such as S3.